# Yocto: Modify the auto load kernel module orders

Tags: yocto

I am writing a out of tree kernel module,as simple we can think it is A, and I use the `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` to auto `insmod` the kernel module during device boot up. `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` will auto insmod the kernel module with no sequence. But the A should be insmoded after B kernel module in sequence.
So Ask for help that If there any ways to Modify the auto load kernel module orders?

I think have two approaches acctualy, one is to add module dependency, But not know how to add?

The other one is to auto load via own systemd service after systemd-modules-load.service instead `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD`. Haven't tried it yet.

And I am not know if yocto already have the mechanism about modifying the auto load kernel module orders?

Answer (score 0):

module load order is an interesting question! Here are a few ideas to make module A load before module B:

1. The items in `/etc/modules-load.d` are probably loaded in appearance order. This file is populated in the `pkg_postinst` step for modules. You could make module B install after module A with:

```
RDEPENDS:module-b += "module-a
```

2. If module B semantically depends on module A, an explicit dependency would be better. `depmod` can automatically make that dependency if you use module A symbols inside module B. Otherwise, try calling:

```c
request_module("module_a");
```

3. Remaining options is to use custom modules loading instead of `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` for module A. You could write another .service file with `Before=systemd-modules-load.service`. You could use the boot parameter `modules_load=` which it probably loads first.